# Is the series absolutely or conditionally convergent or not?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\left(\frac {n+1}{n}\right)^{2n}  $

This is not absolutely convergent because

$$\frac {1}{n}<\left(\frac {1}{n}\right)^{2n}<\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{2n}.$$
I am trying to show the conditional convergence, but the alternating series test is not working.

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n=e^2.$$

So, I was using the ratio test, but I don't know how to compute this: 
$$\left|\dfrac{\left(\frac{n+2}{n+1}\right)^{2n+2}}{\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^{2n}}\right|.$$

I appreciate any hint.

Comment: The inequality $\frac {1}{n}<(\frac {1}{n})^{2n}$ is false.

Comment: The terms don't tend to zero.

Comment: Is the sequence of partial sums Cauchy?

Comment: You already calculated the terms don’t go to $0$, so the series must diverge.

Comment: Iasn't it easier just to note that $(1+1/n)^{2n}>1?$